# finding shortest path between two phrases in a graph

Tags: python, nlp

For the below sentence, I earned a dependency graph, and I transformed this dependency graph to a networkx graph. Now, I would like to find the shortest path between the words `"Acute Kidney Injury"` and `"CYP3A4"`.

Because `"Acute Kidney Injury"` has 3 nodes in the graph, I don't know, how I can find path between the aforementioned words.

Below the dependency_graph of the sentence:

[image: dependency_graph]

Sentence:
`"Acute Kidney Injury from Excessive Potentiation of Calcium-channel Blocker via Synergistic CYP3A4 Inhibition by Clarithromycin Plus Voriconazole."`

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Is unclear (at least to me) what you are asking, please add a small sample input and the expected output

Comment: for example, The shortest path between "Excessive" and "Inhibition" words  in the above sentence

Comment: , will be "Excessive - Potentiation - Injury - Blocker - Inhibition" .

Comment: if both ends of the path are a single node, the shortest path will be found easyly like above example,

Comment: but when an end of the path is a phrase (like "acute kidney injury) i dont know, what is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a non-trivial question I will try to provide some possible directions instead of a clear answer.

According to the question, you are able to find the shortest paths between two nodes in the dependency graph, but not able to do this on a phrase.

You can try to:

1. There are many parsers in NLP tools (like Spacy) that will provide you dependency parse with phrases merged.
2. You can also merge the phrases into a single node from the dependency parse itself. E.g `Acute Kidney` has the dependencies **compound** with `Injury`, meaning `Acute Kidney` is actually a part of the phrase.
3. In such scenarios, you can simply consider the parent node of the phrase in the dependency subtree to calculate the path. E.g, in `Acute Kidney Injury`, `Injury` is the parent node.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: i used stanford dependency parser tool.